# how change documentclass figure environment?

Tags: captions, koma-script

I use `\documentclass [a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}`
for my thesis but realized that I would prefer not to have the spacing between, 
e.g.

```
Figure 3: some caption
          and text
```

but instead have the Figure 3 melting with the caption at least for some images

e.g.

```
   Figure 3: long some
   caption
```

I saw that this is the case if I change from `scrreprt` to `article` but this changes so much other things that I don't want to do that. Are there other solutions?

Comment: Use package  `caption` and `format=plain`.

Answer (score 4):

With the KOMA-Script class you can set the caption indent to `0pt`:

```
\setcapindent{0pt}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\setcapindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\rule{\linewidth}{1cm}
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
  Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.
  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]